# SQL Server 2005: Selecting number of data from a History (From start to end max 100 results)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
 CREATE TABLE tblHistory
    (
      ID INT IDENTITY
             PRIMARY KEY ,
      Added DATETIME ,
      value1 INT ,
      Value2 INT
    )
```

with a lot of history data.

As result I want a maximum of 100 rows but from the beginning to the end.

In this example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe54b/1/0) I've got 197 rows of data in my table.

I want a maximum of 100 rows from beginning to end, in this example.. every second row in my result, so that I don't have more than max 100 rows.

If my `History` table has 500 entries, I want for example every fifth entry from my `History` table and so on...

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select top 100 * FROM tblHistory order by added desc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that `id` has no gaps, the following should do what you want, relatively efficiently:

```
select h.*
from tblHistory h cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from tblHistory) as c
where floor(id * 100.0 / cnt) <> floor((id + 1) * 100.0 / cnt);
```

This will select about 100 rows evenly spaced in the data.  If `id` doesn't meet these conditions, then use `row_number()` in a subquery.

Comment: thanks ive used this. it works really great. And thanks for all the other Answers

Answer (score 2):

to get every fifth entry try this:

```
select *
  from tblHistory
 where id % 5 = 0
```

so if you want to get around 100 entries, try something along the lines of this:

```
select *
  from tblHistory
 where id % (select round(count(*)/100,0) from tblHistory) = 0
```

where you take the number of records in tblHistory, divide it by 100 and use that as the amount of records to skip each time

Answer (score 2):

This is a two-step process:

1. Find the denominator of your row fraction... your row factor. If you want 1 out of every 2 rows, you need a 2. If you want 1 out of every 5 rows, it's a 5. This assumes you're taking a small enough sample that the numerator will always be a 1. If you want something like 2 out of every 3 rows, this changes significantly.
2. Select out the rows to match that factor

You can get both steps into a single statement:

```
select *
from (
   select *, row_number() over (order by Added) Row
   from tblHistory
) h
where h.Row % (SELECT ceiling(COUNT(*) / cast(@DesiredRows as float)) As RowFactor FROM tblHistory) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get just 100 rows from all over the table, ordered by `Added` - you can use this code :

```
WITH GroupedData AS
(
    SELECT 
        h.ID, h.Added, h.Value1, h.Value2,
        GroupNo = NTILE(100) OVER(ORDER BY Added DESC)
    FROM dbo.tblHistory
), 
GroupedDataWithRownum AS
(
    SELECT 
        ID, Added, Value1, Value2,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupNo ORDER BY Added DESC)
    FROM GroupedData
)
SELECT * 
FROM GroupedDataWithRownum
WHERE ROwNUm = 1
```

The first CTE `GroupedData` adds a `GroupNo` from 1 to 100 to each row of your table, basically splitting your table into 100 more or less equal groups of rows.

The second CTE `GroupedDataWithRownum` then adds sequential numbers to each group - starting at 1.

So if you want to get the first entry for each of the 100 groups defined - just select from the second CTE with `RowNum = 1` and voila - you get exactly 100 rows, nicely distributed across your table - and this works no matter how many rows your original table has.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle that has in no way been optimised, but something you can work from:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fe54b/13)

```
SELECT * FROM tblHistory
WHERE ID in (    
    SELECT min(ID) as Id 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT ID, ntile(100) OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS ntile_rank
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Id FROM tblHistory) AS History
) AS ranking
GROUP BY ntile_rank)
```

This basically splits your result set into 100 blocks using the `ntile` function and then using the first `Id` per block to filter your list.